# Passing inputModel instead of request to passport strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using passport local strategy like this:

Config:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        UserPersistenceModel.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (!user) return done(null, false);
            user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if(err) return done(err);
                if(!isMatch) return done(null, false);
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }
));
```

My router definition looks like this:

```
var TokenRouter = function(app, passport, tokenSecret) {
    //Create
    app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) {
                console.log('Unsuccessful login!');
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Login failed!' });
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                console.log('Successful login!');

                //user has authenticated correctly thus we create a JWT token
                var token = jwt.encode(user, tokenSecret);
                res.json({ output : token });
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
};
```

For some reasons I don't fully understand the passport "mechanism". The documentation doesn't look very detailled to me. One question is where the request object (this contains the body which contains the email and the password) is passed to my strategy. How does the strategy gets the email and the password (what's the "source object")?

The reason asking this is that I'd like to use the following inputModel instead of the request being passed to the strategy:

```
var TokenCreateInputModel = function(req) {
    this.email = req.body.email;
    this.password = req.body.password;

    this.validate();
};
TokenCreateInputModel.prototype = Object.create(InputModel);

TokenCreateInputModel.prototype.validate = function() {
    if(!this.email) throw new Error('Email is required!');
    if(this.email.indexOf('@') == -1) throw new Error('Emailsyntax is wrong!');

    if(!this.password) throw new Error('Password is required!');
};

module.exports = TokenCreateInputModel;
```

This inputmodel is converting the request and validating the data. I want to use this input model because it fits better to my architecture (I'm using such inputModels in all other cases ... just not with passport (because of the lack of my understanding), which seems to be inconsistent to me.

Comment: [Look at the source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L69) for inner workings of the strategy where it handles the request object which is passed to it. Basically `passport.authenticate('local', funct...})` return a (middleware) function which is called right afterwards passing to it the `(req,res,next)` parameters.